# How to remove outlier based on manual threshold in ggplot geom_boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following script:

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(mpg, aes(class, hwy)) + geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) + geom_jitter(width = 0.2)
```

It produces plot like this:

[image]

As shown in the plot above. I'd like to remove outlier with `hwy` values <= 10.

Comment: Why do you not just remove those observations before plotting ?

Comment: `ggplot(filter(mpg, hwy >= 10), aes(class, hwy)) + geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) + geom_jitter(width = 0.2)` ?

Comment: @RonakShah I want to maintain the mean and error range  to be the same, only remove in the final image. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the data there are on rows where `hwy <= 10`. For demonstration purposes let's remove rows where `hwy <= 15`. You can remove the rows from the data of the plot.

```
plt<- ggplot(mpg, aes(class, hwy)) + geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) + geom_jitter(width = 0.2)
plt$data <- subset(plt$data, hwy > 15)
plt
```

Answer (score 0):

I would filter the data frame, like so:

```
ggplot(mpg %>% filter(hwy >= 10), aes(class, hwy)) + geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) + geom_jitter(width = 0.2)
```